# Cannot configure static IPv6 (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: networking, server, 19.04, ipv6, static-ip

I'm trying to implement a network for a project where i need a server, a virtual machine running Ubuntu 19.04, with two static ipv4 and ipv6 addresses (one on each interface on the machine) to connect 2 subnet, but editing my `/etc/network/interfaces` file doesn't seem to work.

At the moment my configuration is this:

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
    address 192.168.20.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.20.0
    broadcast 192.168.20.255
    gateway 192.168.20.1

iface enp0s8 inet6 static
    address fc00::2:0:0:0:a
    netmask 64

auto enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet static
    address 192.168.30.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.30.0
    broadcast 192.168.30.255
    gateway 192.168.30.1

iface enp0s9 inet6 static
    address fc00::3:0:0:0:a
    netmask 64
```

Using the command `ip addr show` ipv4 works fine but i can only see one of the 2 static ipv6 addresses (every interface also has its fe80: link-local address).
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check, 1. are you using a correct ipv6 private IP, 2. is your system correctly configured to use netplan xor ifupdown (I assume ifupdown as you are using /etc/network/interfaces file).

1. If you do not have a valid IPv6 address range from your ISP, you can use a private address, in the special IP range of fc00::/7 (as per RFC4193). Note that such addresses will always start with "fd" because the 8th bit must be one (hence fc00::/7 bits). The global ID and subnet ID must be random, and then you can assign anything for the rest (interface).

The addresses fc00::2:0:0:0:a and fc00::3:0:0:0:a are not valid private IP's. Should be fd00:: etc. assuming that was the intention. This could cause issues when assigning the IP's. Try using one of the many online services to generate the private IP's using a certified random generator.

2. Check for netplan vs ifupdown:

netplan (backend: Network-Manager Desktop GUI or systemd-networkd service):

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

Check what netplan is doing when it creates interfaces using:

```
netplan --debug generate --mapping enp0s8
```

ifupdown (backend: networking)

```
systemctl status networking.service
```

Check what interfaces ifupdown actually configured:

```
cat /run/network/ifstate
```

And ensure that the ipv6 interfaces are listed.

Comment: `systemctl status networking.service` shows Active: failed and ifup: failed to bring up enp0s8 (same with enp0s9). `cat /run/network/ifstate` shows only lo, but i also have the enp0s3 interface connected to the internet.

Comment: Using `netplan` i was able to set both the ipv6 address i wanted at the same time, seems to be the way to go from Ubuntu 18.04 and other newer versions